# AWS Elastic Beanstalk logging with python (django)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

How do you manage your application logs in AWS elastic beanstalk? Which file you write you application logs to?

I'm using the following Logging configuration in my development environment but this doesn't work when I deploy in AWS.

```
DEBUG_LOG_DIR = BASE_DIR + "/django_debug.log"
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    # How to format the output
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    # Log handlers (where to go)
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'log_file': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': DEBUG_LOG_DIR,
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        },
    },
    # Loggers (where does the log come from)
    'loggers': {
        'repackager': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'log_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'WARN',
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'log_file'],
            'level': 'WARN',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'log_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a way to do it.

First I connected via ssh to ec2 machine, then I create a folder in /var/log called app_logs with root user:

```
mkdir /var/log/app_logs
```

After that I did the follow:

```
cd /var/log/
chmod g+s app_logs/
setfacl -d -m g::rw app_logs/
chown wsgi:wsgi app_logs/
```

That ensures that all the files created in this folder will have wsgi as owner and will be writable for the group that the file belongs. 
I had to do that because I noticed that the log file created by django app had root as owner and owner group but the application runs through wsgi user.

Finally I changed DEBUG_LOG_DIR to /var/log/app_logs/django_debug.log

Comment: Keep in mind that if you ever need to rebuild your instance this will need to be performed again manually. This will also not be applied to autoscaled instances.

Comment: You can just write the commands in your .ebextensions as a command to execute before application starts to make sure it is always on

Answer (score 41):

I had a similar issue but on Elastic Beanstalk, so I created a config file (e.g. applogs.config) in `.ebextensions` folder of the app. This creates the app-logs folder if it is not there already and sets the file permissions and owner so that the app can write its logs there.

```
commands:
  00_create_dir:
    command: mkdir -p /var/log/app-logs
  01_change_permissions:
    command: chmod g+s /var/log/app-logs
  02_change_owner:
    command: chown wsgi:wsgi /var/log/app-logs
```

Finally, in your Django settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/app-logs/django.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Aditionally, if you want your log to be accessible from beanstalk logs using the web, add this to your file in .ebextensions

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/django.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /var/log/app-logs/django.log
```

Comment: in my setup id had to use another user: `command: chown wsgi:wsgi /var/log/app-logs`

Comment: This should be the correctly accepted answer. If you rebuild the instance with the accepted answer you'll have to re-create the file every time.

Comment: It is actually better to use `/opt/python/log/` for the logs. The directory already exists, no need to create it, and it's packaged when getting log bundle or saving them to cloudwatch.

Comment: And how, exactly, do you manage to give it permissions for it?

Comment: As suggested in another answer, I added the following to avoid one final permission error:
`03_change_default_owner: command: setfacl -d -m g::rw /var/log/app-logs`

Comment: @jmwicks could you improve your comment by explaining the use of this command and the flags you chose, please?

Comment: @jmwicks is right. If you don't use that command, the log file will be created with user root and group wsgi (thanks to `chmod g+s`) but umask 022 will force the file not to be group-writable. One option would be to force os.umask in the django config but the setfacl does this externally. `-m g::rw` means that the files created in that folder will be group writable, regardless of umask.

Comment: I beat my head for hours on why this didn't work for me. I was getting:
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/app-logs/django.log'
It turns out it was because the log file already existed, and I needed to make my chmod and chown recursive. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @ThierryJ.: Your suggestion of using `/opt/python/log` sounds good. That's also what the AWS EB Python Sample Application does: see [python-v1.zip on aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/RelatedResources.html). Note that this works for the sample app without any permissions customization.

Comment: Note for Amazon Linux 2 with gunicorn, the user and group changed from wsgi:wsgi to webapp:webapp

Comment: I notice the default logging is set to require_debug_true. What if you just removed that filter? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/logging/#default-logging-definition

Comment: @djvg it looks like your comment there on /opt/python/log may be outdated as the latest Python sample ZIP uses `LOG_FILE = '/tmp/sample-app.log'` in `application.py`.

Comment: I got the following error: "Command 02_change_owner failed", "chown: invalid user: ‘wsgi:wsgi’", do someone know the solution? I just copied and pasted the command above.

Answer (score 9):

There's a simple way that doesn't require any beanstalk configuration.

In your django settings under **LOGGING** set up a handler directed to the file  **'/opt/python/log/{log_file_name}'**. The logs can then be accessed via the beanstalk environment menu under "Logs".

```
LOGGING = {
    ...,
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/opt/python/log/{log_file_name}',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'debugger': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
}
```

This location is stated in the documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html#health-logs-instancelocation

Comment: I agree that this is the ideal solution. But When I try to implement this I'm getting an error stating that permission is denied to  the generated log file (django.log). If I SSH into the box and chmod 777 the django.log file it works fine. However that is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: If you're running into a permission issue like that, one way is to make an EC2 launch script with write permissions

Comment: Which makes the first sentence of the answer, "There's a simple way that doesn't require any beanstalk configuration", incorrect.

Comment: @JamesParker: possible cause for your permission error [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549321).

Comment: Does AL2 have a similar location?

Answer (score 7):

-- edit --

This answer was originally written for **Amazon Linux AMI**, which has now reached [end-of-life](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/update-on-amazon-linux-ami-end-of-life/).

To keeps things clear and separate, I wrote a [new answer for **Amazon Linux 2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65202757).

-- original answer --

### Summary

The simplest solution, in my opinion, is to log to the `/opt/python/log` folder, as suggested by [bewestphal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48032944) and by @thierry-j (under [steve-dunlop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34819988)).

That is also what the official AWS EB Python *Sample Application* does: see `python-v1.zip` [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/RelatedResources.html#RelatedResources-sampleapps)

The log file will then be included automatically when you request logs from EB.

This solution works out-of-the-box, without any modification of `.ebextensions`, as long as you **do not** call `django-admin.py` (or other django code) in your `.ebextensions`.

However, most apps **do** need to call `django-admin.py` in `.ebextensions`, e.g. in order to `migrate`. That will cause the log file to be created *prematurely*, with `root` owner and `root` group. This leads to permission errors, because the app runs as `wsgi:wsgi`.

This can be fixed by adding a new command, *at the end* of your `container_commands`, to remove the "premature" log file, e.g.:

```
container_commands:
  ...
  9999_remove_root_log_file:
    command: rm /opt/python/log/django.log
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Details below.

### Background

On a standard pre-configured Amazon Linux/Python platform, which uses Apache with mod_wsgi (see [AWS platform docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html)), the `WSGIDaemonProcess` for the Django app runs as user `wsgi` and group `wsgi` (see `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf` on your EC2 instance).

In addition, the *default* folder permissions for the `/opt/python/log` folder (on my standard EC2 instance) are: `drwxrwxr-x 3 root wsgi 4096 Mar  5 14:08 .`

That is, the `wsgi` group has all permissions (`rwx`), so the Django app (group `wsgi`) can create log files there.

This works, out-of-the-box, as demonstrated by the official AWS EB Python Sample Application ([python-v1.zip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/RelatedResources.html#RelatedResources-sampleapps)).

However, if you do anything in your `.ebextensions` that causes the `logging` file-handler to be initialized (like calling `django-admin.py`), it will break.

### Permission issues

Here's how using `django-admin.py` in `.ebextensions` breaks your log file permissions:

Elastic Beanstalk `container_commands`, in `.ebextensions`, are executed as the `root` user (see [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html)).

If you call `django-admin.py` in any of the `container_commands`, e.g. with `collectstatic` or `migrate`, that will cause your logging file handler(s) to be initialized.
If the specified log file does not exist yet, at that time, it will be created, with `root` owner and `root` group.

That means the Django app, running as part of the `wsgi` group, will not have permission to write to the log file (which belongs to the `root` group).

This leads to permission errors, e.g.: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/python/log/django.log'`

### How to reproduce

The following snippet illustrates the permissions issue and shows how to fix it.

To reproduce the issue, add these `container_commands` to a clean project (e.g. following the [AWS EB Django tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html)), configure Django `settings.py` to log to `/opt/python/log/django.log`, deploy to AWS EB, then check the `eb-activity.log` to see the output of the container commands.

```
...

container_commands:
  0100_show_current_user:
    # show that we are running as root user
    command: whoami
  0200_try_to_remove_log_file:
    # we need a clean slate for this example (make sure no log file owned by wsgi is present)
    command: rm /opt/python/log/django.log
    ignoreErrors: true
  0300_break_log_file_permissions:
    # this causes a new log file to be created, owned by root:root (instead of wsgi:wsgi)
    command: django-admin.py
  0400_show_log_file_permissions:
    # prove that a log file was created by root, and show folder permissions
    command: ls -la /opt/python/log
  0500_fix_by_removing_log_file_after_all_django_admin_calls:
    # remove the log file created by django-admin.py, to ensure that a new log file will  
    # be created when the server starts, owned by wsgi:wsgi
    command: rm /opt/python/log/django.log
    ignoreErrors: true
```

### DRY solution

So, *there is no need to mess with file/folder permissions* explicitly.

If you don't call django code in `.ebextensions`, logging to `/opt/python/log` works, out-of-the-box.

If you do call django code in `.ebextensions`, e.g. `django-admin.py collectstatic`, simply remove the log file *at the end* of your `container_commands` section.

NOTE: If you want to log files to persist between deployments, only remove them if they are owned by `root`.

Here's a DRY example:

In `.ebextensions` config:

```
option_settings:
  # create EB environment property for the log file path
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    LOG_FILE_PATH: /opt/python/log/django.log
...

container_commands:
  ...
  # django code called here, e.g. "django-admin.py collectstatic"
  ...
  9999_remove_any_existing_django_log_files:
    command: rm $LOG_FILE_PATH      
    ignoreErrors: true
```

and in `settings.py`:

```
...
# get log path from environment variable, with fallback for local development
log_file_path = os.getenv('LOG_FILE_PATH', 'local.log')
# use this as 'filename' for the file handler, as described in the other answers
...
```

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: This works (for me) on Amazon Linux AMI, but I haven't tested it (yet) on [Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Comment: It does not work on Amazon Linux 2 out of the box. Possibly because there's no /opt/python/log (or /opt/python for that matter). I'm still trying to see where the recommended place for logs are. I will probably fall back on /var/log/, creating an app-logs subfolder.

Comment: @Oded: According to the AWS docs about [migrating to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html), the application now resides in `/var/app/current`. See the Python section.

Comment: Got it. I actually like not having my logs clobbered when the app is reinstalled, so I can compare what happened in a previous version when debugging a problem.

Comment: @Oded: I'm not sure if there is an alternative for `/opt/python/log` that is equally convenient. I could not find any recommendations in the AWS docs, but the official Python sample application for EB on Amazon Linux 2 now logs to the `/tmp` folder, and uses custom logging tasks to include these logs. See updated answer for details.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is for **Amazon Linux 2** only. For those who have not migrated [yet](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/update-on-amazon-linux-ami-end-of-life/), please see my [old answer for Amazon Linux AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549321).

### Background

The [official AWS Python sample-application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/python.zip) for **Amazon linux 2** uses the `/tmp` folder for logging.

However, custom log files added to `/tmp` are **not** included automatically when requesting logs from Elastic Beanstalk. To include custom log files, we need to create logging tasks in subfolders of `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks` on the EC2 instance. See [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html#health-logs-extend) in the documentation.

The sample app ([source](https://elasticbeanstalk-platform-assets-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/stalks/eb_python37_amazon_linux_2_1.0.623.0_20200803061640/sampleapp/EBSampleApp-Python.zip)) accomplishes this using `.ebextensions`. However, the [AWS Linux 2 migration docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html) suggest we should use `.platform` hooks instead:

> We recommend using platform hooks to run custom code on your environment instances. You can still use commands and container commands in .ebextensions configuration files, but they aren't as easy to work with. For example, writing command scripts inside a YAML file can be cumbersome and difficult to test.

This has the additional advantage that output from platform hooks is collected in a separate log file, viz. `/var/log/eb-hooks.log`, which makes debugging a bit easier.

### DRY logging setup for a basic Django app on **Amazon Linux 2**

Log level and log path are defined in *one* place, as Elastic Beanstalk environment properties, e.g. in `.ebextensions/options.config`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    LOG_LEVEL: INFO
    DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH: /tmp/django-app.log
    ...
```

The `DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH` environment property can now be used in a platform hook to create logging tasks:

#### .platform/hooks/postdeploy/020_create_logging_tasks.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
TASKS_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks
# include all app log files in bundle logs (replaces ".log" by "*")
echo "${DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH//.log/*}" > "$TASKS_DIR/bundlelogs.d/01-app-log.conf"
# include current app log file in tail logs
echo $DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH > "$TASKS_DIR/taillogs.d/01-app-log.conf"
```

Note that the platform hooks require execution permission, e.g. `chmod +x 020_create_logging_tasks.sh`. On windows you can use `git` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693614).

To prevent permission issues, we use another platform hook to ensure that the log file is always owned by `webapp`. Note this hook runs before the logging-tasks hook:

#### .platform/hooks/postdeploy/010_create_log_file.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if test -f "$DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH";
then
  echo "$DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH exists"
else
  # create log file
  touch $DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH
fi

# set log file owner (we are currently "root", but the app runs as "webapp")
chown webapp:webapp $DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH
```

We also use the `LOG_LEVEL` and `DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH` environment properties in our Django settings:

#### settings.py

```
...
# basic logging with file rotation ()
log_level = os.getenv('LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO')
handlers = dict(file={'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                      'filename': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_FILE_PATH'),
                      'when': 'midnight',
                      'interval': 1,
                      'backupCount': 1,
                      'encoding': 'utf-8'})
loggers = dict(django=dict(level=log_level, handlers=['file']),
               myapp=dict(level=log_level, handlers=['file']))
LOGGING = dict(version=1,
               disable_existing_loggers=False,
               handlers=handlers,
               loggers=loggers)
...
```

Some notes:

- We normally specify custom `formatters` as well, but I left those out for clarity.
- The application itself can now be found on the EC2 instance in `/var/app/current`. Also see [extending EB Linux platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.example) for more details.
- The application now runs as `webapp` with group `webapp`.
- `eb ssh` is your friend. See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html).
- We also use platform hooks to run Django's `migrate` and `collectstatic` commands, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199647).

EDIT:

As pointed out by @hax0 in the comments, file permission issues may arise *if* you try to run `manage.py` commands on the EC2 instance, using SSH, *after deployment*.

For example, when using `eb ssh`, you are logged in as `ec2-user`, but the log file is owned by the `webapp` user, and, by default, only the owner has write permission (`644`). Thus, when running `python manage.py` as `ec2-user`, you will get an error saying it cannot configure the log file handler because permission is denied.

A quick & dirty workaround is to change file permissions *temporarily*, e.g. using

```sh
sudo chmod 646 /tmp/django-app.log
```

Another workaround would be to run `manage.py` as the `webapp` user, for example like so:

```sh
sudo su - webapp <<'EOF'
source $(find /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate)
export $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config --output YAML environment | 
         sed -r 's/: /=/' | xargs)
python3 /var/app/current/manage.py showmigrations
EOF
```

Comment: Deployment works but when we ssh into the instance and try to `python manage.py shell`, it gives permission error on `/tmp/django-app.log` file

Comment: @hax0: Yes, I can confirm this. It happens because you are `ec2-user`, whereas the log file belongs to `webapp` (user and group). By default, only the log file owner (i.e. `webapp`) has write permission (`644`). If this is incidental, a quick & dirty workaround is to change file permissions *temporarily*, e.g. `sudo chmod 646 /tmp/django-app.log`. If it is a structural thing, you could do something similar in a `.platform` hook. Do keep in mind any security implications. A better alternative might be to try to run the command as `webapp`.

Comment: @hax0: `manage.py shell` works for me after changing file permissions. I did manage to run other `manage.py` commands as the `webapp` user, but could not get `manage.py shell` to work that way. See edit in answer.

Comment: Using this exact solution on Amazon Linux 2, deployment fails (Gunicorn + Django + Nginx) with a `Permission denied: '/tmp/django-app.log'`. Perhaps that is because of the `manage.py` commands being run in `container_commands`.

Comment: `django-app.log` appears to be mode 0600, owned by root:root. I believe that's because some other command must be run by the root user, which generates that file as owned by root. (Again, assuming that's the stuff in `container_commands` but maybe something else.)

Comment: @BradSolomon On Amazon Linux 2 we do not use any `container_commands` at all: we use platform hooks to run `manage.py` etc. If you *do* call `manage.py` in the old `container_commands`, I expect that could indeed lead to permission issues similar to the ones described in my [other answer (for Amazon Linux "1")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549321).

Comment: Thanks, yes; once I combined the knowledge that you shared from those two answers, that made sense, and was fixed by a final `rm` call in `container_commands` to remove the root-owned log file so that it could be regenerated by the non-root user.

Comment: @BradSolomon: I updated the answer with an example of another platform hook that ensures `webapp` always owns the log file. That should prevent permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner in terms of linux permissions, it took me some time to get it to work. Summarising the above given answers the following finally worked for me:

logging.config

```
commands:
  00_create_dir:
    command: mkdir -p /var/log/app-logs
  01_change_permissions:
    command: chmod g+s /var/log/app-logs
  02_change_default_owner:
    command: setfacl -d -m g::rw /var/log/app-logs
  03_change_owner:
    command: chown wsgi:wsgi /var/log/app-logs
```

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/var/log/app-logs/django.log',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
}
```

With this I can see the logs as a separate section using 'eb logs' or within the Beanstalk environment, section "logs".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `gunicorn`, then you can use this flag:

```
gunicorn --access-logfile=-
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.0.2

```
commands:
  00_create_dir:
    command: mkdir -p /var/log/app-logs
  01_change_permissions:
    command: chmod g+s /var/log/app-logs
  02_change_owner:
    command: chown webapp:webapp /var/log/app-logs
```

and the log file setting in Django,

```
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
    'logfile': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': "/var/log/app-logs/django.log",
        'formatter': 'standard',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

Make sure that the log file has the correct ownership and group configuration, the owner and group should be webapp:wehapp as follows

```
[ec2-user@ip-171-11-1-8 app-logs]$ ll django.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 webapp webapp 1120 Jul 29 01:08 django.log
```

Answer (score -4):

By default in elasticbeanstalk, you can see the django error logs here.

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Comment: No, Django server errors do not show up in this file.

Comment: they _might_ end up there, but that's only on some cases.

Comment: See [this discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=397682#397682) on AWS forums.