# Django Logging with Elastic Beanstalk (AWS)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a web service built on Django/Python at AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. I am using Django's logging feature to log website use and related data. While that worked fine with local testing, I an unable to get this to work with Beanstalk.

My code to log in `settings.py` is:

```
# Django Logging

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'spareguru.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
         },
        'customer': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
         },
    }
}
```

The error I get while deploying to Beanstalk is:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/python/bundle/3/app/spareguru.log'
```

I also tried creating a file using `.ebextensions` and making `wsgi` the owner of that file but that didn't work either.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have sufficient rights on the server for create log file. Сonfigure SSH and using CHMOD to change permission for folder

Configure the environment of your Elastic Beanstalk Application (for SSH) - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742478/ssh-to-elastic-beanstalk-instance)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for the OP, but this may be useful for others:

If you call e.g. `django-admin.py migrate`, or other django code, in your `.ebextensions` `container_commands`, that will cause the log file to be created with user `root` and group `root` (unless the file already exists).

In that case, you may need to change the file permissions *after* all the django calls have been made (in `.ebextensions`), or just remove the log file, as explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549321).