# Can't get flask to log to opt/python/log on Elastic Beanstalk AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I have been trying to get my Flask app to log to a log file. In elastic beanstalk I have a logger in my flask app that logs files to

```
opt/python/log
```

The file is successfully created but when I try to do something like

```
log.warning('ERROR')
```

The line does not show up correctly. I have tested to make sure my logger works correctly on localhost. I have read many stack overflow responses and believe it's a permissions issue, however when I try adding

```
commands:
  01_change_permissions:
command: chmod g+s /opt/python/log
  02_change_owner:
command: chown root:wsgi /opt/python/log
```

to

```
.ebextensions
```

Or even something like

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/history.conf" :
     mode: "000755"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       /opt/log/python/history.log
```

Nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: when you say:  "Does not show up correctly"  what do you mean?  Are you using Cloudwatch logs?  or are you ssh-ing into the instance and checking the log manuallY?

Comment: I think you need `sudo` to be able to write into `/opt/`

Answer (score 0):

Read the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/).

I think you should use logger like: `app.logger.warning('ERROR')`.

Comment: No that's not the issue. In my app I import the log so the logger properly works. It's a permissions issue

Comment: If you haven’t solved the problem yet, you can:
change your log file to `/tmp/tmp.log` to debug

Answer (score 0):

There were two pieces to the puzzle.

**Firstly:**

The logger needs to be connected to the application as per this GitHub

https://gist.github.com/sm-azure/c4b2edd8a726d81f42c98ee40fc1730a

```
application.logger.addHandler(YourFileHandler)
```

**Secondly:**

You need to call the logger via the application.logger, not just the logger; i.e.

```
application.logger.debug("This text will log")
```

The following form will NOT WORK:

```
logger.debug("This text will NOT log")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulling from [this answer regarding logging for  django app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34819988/5679079).

In command 2 you need to change both the owner and group of the directory to be: wsgi.

A third command is also necessary to change the default owner

also, I had to add a third command to set the file access control.  Someone smarter than me can chime in with why it is necessary, but without it, I've run into problems.

your .ebextensions config file should be:

```
commands:
  01_change_permissions:
    command: chmod g+s /opt/python/log
  02_change_owner:
    command: chown wsgi:wsgi /opt/python/log
  03_change_default_owner:
    command: setfacl -d -m g::rw /opt/python/log
```