# Elastic Beanstalk: log task customization on Amazon Linux 2 platforms

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm wondering how to do [log task customization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html#health-logs-extend) in the new Elastic Beanstalk platform (the one based on Amazon Linux 2). Specifically, I'm comparing:

- **Old**: Single-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.14.3
- **New**: Single-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.0

(My question actually has nothing to do with Docker as such, I'm speculating the problem exist for any of the new Elastic Beanstalk platforms).

Previously I could follow Amazon's recipe, meaning put a file into `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/` and it would then be acted upon. This is no longer true.

Has this changed? I can't find it [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html). Anyone been successful in doing log task customization on the newer Elastic Beanstalk platform? If so, how?

### Minimal working example

I've created a minimal working example and deployed on both platforms.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY daemon-run.sh /daemon-run.sh
RUN chmod +x /daemon-run.sh
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/daemon-run.sh"]
```

`Dockerrun.aws.json`:

```js
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Logging": "/var/mydaemon"
}
```

`daemon-run.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting daemon" # output to stdout
mkdir -p /var/mydaemon/deeperlogs
while true; do
   echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z')  Hello World" >> /var/mydaemon/deeperlogs/app_$$.log
   sleep 5
done
```

`.ebextensions/mydaemon-logfiles.config`:

```
files: 
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/mydaemon-logs.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/deeperlogs/*.log
```

If I do "Full Logs" action on the old platform I would get a ZIP with my `deeperlogs` included
inside `var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app`. On the new platform I don't.

### Investigation

If you look on the disk you'll see that the new Elastic Beanstalk doesn't have a `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks` folder at all, unlike the old one. Hmm.

Comment: You can create log tasks using Amazon Linux 2 `.platform/hooks/`, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65202757). Based on the [Amazon Linux 2 migration docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html), I believe this is preferred over using `.ebextensions`.

Comment: @djvg. Whether or not fiddling with the log task configuration is done via `.ebextensions` or via platform hooks (now preferred as you mention) is an implementation detail of this question. The issue was that - up until the Aug 2020 release of the AL2 platforms - it simply wasn't possible to do log task customization for EB AL2 platforms the way it was documented by Amazon.  Now it [has been fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63278952/1504556) and you can fiddle with the files in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks` using the method of your choice (yes, hooks method preferred).

Comment: @peterh: Thanks for the explanation. That is more or less what I understood from the question and the accepted answer below. I just thought I would mention the platform hooks option, as that had not been mentioned anywhere on this page yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon has fixed this problem in version of the Elastic Beanstalk AL2 platforms [released on 04-AUG-2020](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/relnotes/release-2020-08-04-al2.html).

It has been fixed so that log task customization on AL2-based platforms now works the way it has always worked (i.e. on the prevision generation AL2018 platforms) and you can therefore follow the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html#health-logs-extend) in order to make this happen.

Succesfully tested with platform *"Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.0"*. If you (still) use *"Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.x"* then you must use the undocumented workaround [described in Marcin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61995539/2282938) but you are probably better off by upgrading your platform version.

Answer (score 3):

On Amazon Linux 2 the folder is:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle
```

The `.ebextensions/mydaemon-logfiles.config` should be:

```
files: 
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle/mydaemon-logs.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       /var/mydaemon/deeperlogs/*.log

container_commands:
  append_deeperlogs_to_applogs:
    command: echo -e "\n/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/deeperlogs/*" >> /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle/applogs
```

The `mydaemon-logfiles.config` also adds `deeperlogs` into `applogs` file. Without it `deeperlogs` will not be included in the download log zip bundle. Which is intresting, because the folder will be in the correct location, i.e., `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/deeperlogs/`. But without being explicitly listed in `applogs`, it will be skipped when zip bundle is being generated.

I tested it with single docker environment (3.0.1).

The full log bundle successful contained `deeperlogs` with correct log data:

[image]

[image]

Hope that this will help. I haven't found any references for that. AWS documentaiton does not document this, as it is mostly based on Amazon Linux 1, not Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: Does this work for the PHP platform too? I tried this approach and it doesn't seem to work here. No custom logs are published in CloudWatch. Only the default ones. Unfortunately, the AWS documentation is really bad here...

Comment: @AlexanderBarton Its for docker env. But I guess it could be modified to work on other environments as well.

Comment: If I only knew how to make this working again. On Amazon Linux 1, I had some boilerplate code ready to publish custom logs. But it has changed and I'm trying to figure it out for hours now. If I find a solution, I will share it :)

Comment: Thanks for this. It's extremely frustrating that Amazon's "latest" docs refer to outdated information

Comment: @Andy Yes. I feel your pain.

Comment: This answer now only applies to Elastic Beanstalk AL2-based platforms released **prior** to 04-AUG-2020. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63278952/2282938).

Comment: @lbruun Thanks for letting me know. But your question is from may and my answer well. Not August.

Comment: I agree. Your answer was correct back then which is why the bounty was awarded to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As of **2021/11/05**, I tried the accepted answer and various other examples including the latest official documentation on using the .ebextensions folder with *.config files without success.

Most likely something I was doing wrong but here's what worked for me.
The version I'm using: **Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.8**

Simply, **add a volume to your docker-compose.yml file** to share your application logs to the Elastic Beanstalk log directory.

Example docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      # "${EB_LOG_BASE_DIR}/<service name>:<log directory inside container>
      - "${EB_LOG_BASE_DIR}/app:/var/www/html/application/logs" # ADD THIS LINE
    env_file:
      - .env
```

For more info, here's the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-env-cfg.dc-customized-logging) I followed.

Hopefully, this helps future readers like myself