# Cloudwatch logs only updates on deploy

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a single container on elastic beanstalk.
It's a .net core 2.2 application deployed with a docker container running microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime.

I've been trying to setup logging to cloudwatch, and I went into
Elastic Beanstalk -> Environments -> my-environment -> Configuration
and enabled "log streaming" (rotate logs is disabled)

I could now see my log's in cloudwatch, and I can see the log statements from my application in:
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/my-environment/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log

The problem is, that they are never updated. The only time more data is put into the logs, is if I redeploy the application (even after 12H, there's still nothing new in the logs).

I've tried adding a file:
.ebextensions/logs.config with the content:

```
option_settings:
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
option_name: StreamLogs
value: true
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
option_name: DeleteOnTerminate
value: false
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
option_name: RetentionInDays
value: 7
```

But it's the same. The content in the logs is only updated when I redeploy the application.
Secondly, I followed this:
[Elastic Beanstalk Single Container Docker - use awslogs logging driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979394/elastic-beanstalk-single-container-docker-use-awslogs-logging-driver)

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: StreamLogs
    value: true
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: DeleteOnTerminate
    value: false
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: RetentionInDays
    value: 14

files:
  "/etc/awslogs/config/stdout.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/containers/docker-stdout]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`/docker-stdout.log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/containers/*-stdouterr.log

commands:
  "00_restart_awslogs":
    command: service awslogs restart
```

What am I missing? There isn't a lot of traffic on the site, but shouldn't the logs be updated at least every 5 minutes or so?  I've been reading about file_fingerprint_lines and setting awslogs as driver on docker, but can't seem to get any of that to work.

I don't have much experience with EBS or Cloudwatch, so any help is highly appreciated. One of the problems is, that I don't really know where to look for debugging this

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201006/elastic-beanstalk-log-task-customization-on-amazon-linux-2-platforms/61995539#61995539) question? Also do you run single-docker or multi-docker environmnet on EB?

Comment: Thanks, i haven't seen that answer before. I'm going to try it out tonight. It's a single docker instance.

Comment: I've made a bit progress, or at least, I've got some pointers on what's wrong. I SSH'ed into the instance, and started looking at logs. I can see that the stderr log is updating, but I get the following error in my awslogs.log:
cwlogs.push.stream - WARNING - 6563 - Thread-1 - No file is found with given path '/var/log/containers/*-stdouterr.log'.

there is no /var/log/containers/ folder, so I'll will look into how to change it to look the correct place tomorrow again

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved, by having this in my .config file:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: StreamLogs
    value: true
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: DeleteOnTerminate
    value: false
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: RetentionInDays
    value: 14

files:
  "/etc/awslogs/config/stdout.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/containers/docker-stdout]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`/docker-stdout.log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/*-stdouterr.log
```

The answer itself is actually not as interesting, as how I got it debugged (posted here in case it will help others):

1. SSH into the instance by using `eb ssh`
2. Found the log: /var/log/awslogs.log and saw the error: `cwlogs.push.stream - WARNING - 6563 - Thread-1 - No file is found with given path '/var/log/containers/*-stdouterr.log'`
3. I followed the path (/var/log/containers) only to find that the folder structure did not exist. From the logs that was send to cloudwatch, I could see the path was: `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/` which I checked, and found the log files.
4. From some of the other questions that I've been reading, I could see that the configuration for awslogs (which is the agent sending output to aws) was located in: `/etc/awslogs/config/stdout.conf`. Looking in this file, I saw the path `/var/log/containers/*-stdouterr.log`
5. I changed the path to `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/*-stdouterr.log` and restarted the awslogs service `sudo service awslogs restart`

Now I could see the log being updated.
Why it did send logs to cloudwatch on deploy, I don't know, but the above fixed the issue