# How do I address "OSError: mysql_config not found" error during Elastic Beanstalk deployment?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, flask-sqlalchemy

**Problem**

I am trying to deploy a very simple app on Elastic Beanstalk with a small database backend. I try to install `mysqlclient` as part of the process outlined by AWS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface). However, when I deploy my app, I get the following error from my Elastic Beanstalk logs as it tries to download the package:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz (87 kB)

2020/08/21 20:30:16.419082 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bz45889a/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bz45889a/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-1tyle8mv
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bz45889a/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-bz45889a/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-bz45889a/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-bz45889a/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
```

**Question**

The `mysqlclient` is the AWS recommended driver to connect to a MySQL database in RDS using Flask or Django. How do I get it installed with Elastic Beanstalk?

**Context**

I've tried to implement my architecture with either (1) a database *within* the Elastic Beanstalk environment or (2) a regularly deployed RDS instance *outside* the Elastic Beanstalk environment. In this case, we're going with option (1).

I can't install mysql-server or other packages using `apt-get` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface) very easily, which is why I hope this isn't labeled as a duplicate. I don't have access to the underlying servers. I attempted to using platform hooks and .ebextensions, but I [wasn't able to get that to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399252/how-do-you-add-chmod-x-permission-to-an-aws-elastic-beanstalk-platform-hook/63403574?noredirect=1#comment112144355_63403574). In this post, I'm trying to step back and see if there is another avenue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Amazon linux 2 you should be able to install it with `yum`. Thus, you can have in your `.ebextensions` a file called, e.g. `01_packages.config` with the content:

```
packages: 
    yum:
        MySQL-python: []
```

You can add further yum dependencies if you require more.

Comment: Thanks for helping me through this adventure. This works! Another hurdle overcome.

Comment: @whoopscheckmate No problem. Glad it worked out :-)

Comment: For those who this didn't solve the problem like me, you have to add the python3-devel: [] and mariadb-devel: [] like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111066/mysqlclient-installation-error-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add what worked for me, which was slightly different from the rest.

Go to this link to see how to set up the folder for your yum packages -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html
(basically make a .ebextensions folder in your projects root)

Then inside that make a 01_packages.config file as suggested by Marcin, and add in this code:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    python3-devel: []
    mariadb-devel: []
```

Worked for me uploading to AWS beanstalk and code pipeline via GitHub. Python 3.6 and using flask-mysqldb